# Enable to edit after a checkbox

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with some information shown, but I would like to able to edit after I click the checkbox above. [image]

```
 <asp:Button ID="Backbtn" runat="server" Text="Back" Width="84px" 
    onclick="Backbtn_Click" />
 <br /><br />

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="check" Text="Check"/>

<table class="T-Table" >
<tr>
    <th colspan="6"><em>IT INTERNAL USE</em></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="180px">Doc.No </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td width="160px">
        <asp:Label ID="DocNo" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
           <%--     <td width="180px">Job Complete Date </td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td width="160px">



                </td>   --%>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Received Date :</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="RDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>Response Time (HR) :</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="Response_T" runat="server" TextMode="DateTimeLocal"></asp:TextBox>


    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td>Remarks </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td colspan="5"><asp:TextBox ID="Remarks" runat="server"  Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"
       Columns="80"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Cost charge to Department </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="Cost" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="Progress" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Done" Value="Done"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="In Progress" Value="In Progress"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="Pending"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
```

Here are some html code. I would like to add a function so that all the information can be editable after I click the Checkbox.
Thank you

Comment: so... how does this related to c# and linq..? any code and expected behaviour..? beside screenshot..?

Comment: `if(chk.Checked) txt.Enabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with C# or Linq here (as you tagged).

Assuming you are working on an ASP.NET application

1. Enable the checkbox *AutoPostback*. ie, Set *AutoPostback* property of the checkbox to *true*.
2. Then on page load or `checkbox` checked change event, enable the `textbox`.

eg. name of text editor is `txtRemarks` and checkbox name to be `chkRemarksEditor`

on chkRemarksEditor Checked change event :-

```
txtRemarks.Enabled = chkRemarksEditor.Checked;
```